# Parsing complex strings

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am trying to parse out a database with certain definitions. A definition is essentially a string with IDs and relationships between them.

For example: `(A,((B,C) (D,E))) F`
where a space means `AND` and a comma means `OR`. 
Based on the definitions I want to make lists of possible combinations. In this example the possible combinations would be:

- [A,F]
- [B,D,F]
- [B,E,F]
- [C,D,F]
- [C,E,F]

I tried filtering out groups between parentheses using regular expresssions and to make a tree structure that would fit F as the root and make leafs based on the other possibilities, but it failed especially on more complex examples.
One of the most complex examples will be:

> (K01647,K05942) (K01681,K01682) (K00031,K00030) (K00164+K00658+K00382,K00174+K00175-K00177-K00176) (K01902+K01903,K01899+K01900,K18118) (K00234+K00235+K00236+K00237,K00239+K00240+K00241-(K00242,K18859,K18860),K00244+K00245+K00246-K00247) (K01676,K01679,K01677+K01678) (K00026,K00025,K00024,K00116)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to 1) Parse and expression then 2) Convert it into Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF). Have a look at this library: https://github.com/bastikr/boolean.py

Comment: Or perhaps http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html

Comment: @eddiewould Thank you for your suggestions. Boolean.py lets my easily create the expression, but I cannot seem to find out how to extract all possibilities.

Comment: See my answer using Sympy below

Comment: What do '+' and '-' represent?

Comment: @eddiewould sorry I forgot to mention those, '-'  means optional, so for my purposes I will just ignore these and remove them. '+' means also 'AND' (the database uses both spaces and + for the AND operator to distinguish between two different kind of structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using Sympy:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_dnf

# Convert to format Sympy likes
expr_text = "(A,((B,C) (D,E))) F".lower().replace(" ", " & ").replace(",", " | ")

# Create symbols we need 
a, b, c, d, e, f = symbols('a b c d e f')

# Parse expression using our symbols. 
expr = parse_expr(expr_text, global_dict=globals())`

to_dnf(expr)
```

Gives something like

```
(a & f) | (b & d & f) | (b & e & f) | (c & d & f) | (c & e & f)
```

Comment: Sympy has a live shell where you can play with it: http://live.sympy.org/

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for.